# I need help with trying to put craft on a staging subdomain

Tags: subdomain, staging

Hi can anyone tell me if these settings are correct? All I am seeing is a blank page on the front end and the admin url.

This is the structure I have locally and it all works fine:

```
/Root
    - .env
    - /config
    - /modules
    - /storage
    - /templates
    - /vendor
    - /web
         - /assets
         - /cpresources
         - index.php
```

This is the structure I have on remote:

```
/Root
    - /craft
       - .env
       - /config
       - /modules
       - /storage
       - /templates
       - /vendor
    - /public_html
         - /staging
            - /assets
            - /cpresources
            - index.php
```

I've used PhPmyAdmin and created and uploaded the database and user and imported table data.
In .env Ive changed

```
DB_DRIVER=mysql
DB_SERVER=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=8889
DB_DATABASE=sitecms
DB_USER=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
DB_SCHEMA=
DB_TABLE_PREFIX=table_
```

to

```
DB_DRIVER=mysql
DB_SERVER=#.###.##.###[server ip]
DB_PORT=8890
DB_DATABASE=thesite_sitecms
DB_USER=thesite_siteuser
DB_PASSWORD=###########
DB_SCHEMA=
DB_TABLE_PREFIX=table_
```

But I don't know how to change the path or what else I need to do. In index.php I have tried changing

```
define('CRAFT_BASE_PATH', dirname(__DIR__));
```

to

```
define('CRAFT_BASE_PATH', dirname('../../craft'));
```

but I'm still just getting a white page with no error. I'm pretty sure the subdomain is set up correctly as I have changed the index.php in the staging folder with some text and I can see that text in the url staging.mydomain.com.

I've also changed in general.php

```
'@baseUrl' => 'http://192.168.1.10:8890/',
```

to

```
'@baseUrl' => 'http://staging.mydomain.com:8890/',
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to have a different folder structure on the remote? Seems to be inviting a lot of avoidable pain - just make it standard.

Comment: Yes I'm struggling could you give me an answer as to how the structure should be for a subdomain?

Comment: I've recreated my local setup exactly in a subdomain and still getting a blank page.

Comment: It could be lots of different things - you need to ensure `devMode` is switched on in order to see Craft's error messages, and also check your server error log in case there's a problem prior to reaching Craft.

Comment: You sure CRAFT_BASE_PATH is set correctly? You can put a die(CRAFT_BASE_PATH) statement directly after constant definition in the index.php. Also check permissions.